# Accessibility in .Net Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, class, class-library

I am working on a class Library and I'm having troubles with accessibility. My class library contains several internal classes which shouldn't be accessed from other applications. Instead I want to create a Singleton Main Class that contains Instances of all the internal classes, so other applications can access the Main class and then use the internal classes from that instance. The picture below explains the hierarchy.

[image]

I've tried making the Main Class public and the Internal Classes internal, however this gives me the error Error "**Inconsistent accessibility**". My Main Class looks like this:

```
public class Main
{
    private static Main Instance;
    public static Main GetInstance()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
            Instance = new Main();
        return Instance;
    }

    public Debugging Debugger = new Debugging();
}
```

And one of my Internal Classes (Debugging) looks like this:

```
internal class Debugging
{
    Content....
}
```

So I'm hoping that someone can help me to figure out how to make the Internal Classes only accessible through my singleton Main Class.

Comment: The easiest way right now would probably be to simply make the classes `public`, but their constructors `internal`. This will let you easily expose the class and its members but external assemblies won't be able to instantiate one of their own.

Comment: If you only want `Debugging` to be accessible/visible only in the `Class Library`, then make the class `internal`, and declare it as `internal Debugging Debugger = new Debugging()` in `Main`.

Comment: Thanks, do you wanna make your first comment an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive from your question what your intent is so I'll break it into two options:

#### You want `Debugging` accessible to external assemblies, but only via `Main`

There are a few ways how to do this, but the simplest right now for you would be to keep `Debugging` `public`, but define only `internal` constructors. This will allow its usage but external assemblies won't be able to instantiate them, thus forcing them to access the instance created on `Main`

```
public class Debugging
{
    internal Debugging() { }
}
```

#### You don't want `Debugging` accessible to external assemblies, and but still accessible within your class assembly via `Main`

Simply update the accessibility modifier for `Main.Debugger` to be `internal`

```
internal Debugging Debugger = new Debugging();
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I want the 'Debugging' accessible to external assemblies. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set all of you class `public` if you have some `public` access to them (via the `Main` class).

Otherwise you can set the internal class as `internal` and provide a set of properties in the `Main` class (that wrap internal classes' fields/methods) in order to access their field/methods. You can set the constructors of internal class as `internal` in order to avoid those class instantiations.

In general: Every field/method exposed from a `public` class should have a `public` return type.

[Some MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd74a9ww.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the Debugger class outside the Library you need to change the access modeifier to public. As suggested make the constructor as internal so no one outside the assembly can create an instance of those classes.